# How to publish multiple new function triggers to existing Azure Functions App?

Tags: function, azure, publish

I have an existing Azure Function app with a Trigger (trigger1). My current code has 5 Triggers. When I publish to the Function App using Visual Studio 2019, I can see that it published successfully to the development slot of the Function App. But when I go onto the Function app in the azure portal, I don't see the new Triggers. What could be the problem?

When I look at the Function resource under the dev slot in VS Cloud Explorer, I can see the files there too.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v1</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Business\blankblank.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Types\blank2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What do you mean 5 triggers? You mean 5 functions?

Comment: Yeah 5 functions in the functions app

Comment: When I publish from VS to a new function app, all 5 functions show up fine.

Comment: Maybe you could use `func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>` to deploy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#project-file-deployment